# Ruby on Rails Circumstantial Controller Action JavaScript Response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Say I've got requests: `Request`. A request must be approved or declined by an administrator.

I'm designing a UI with an approval/decline button on the index page for requests. Similar to the delete button generated by scaffolding.

The issue I'm facing is that I want to respond to an AJAX request differently depending on the page it came from.

I have an action `update` that could potentially be used, but the JavaScript response in `update.js.erb` was designed for an edit page that has a form `/requests/1/edit`.

The only work around I've managed feels like its breaking conventions and creates a useless action that duplicates code.

What I've done is added the action `update_status` that has it's own `*.js.erb` response to do something like UI changes on an index page.

I feel like what I'm trying to do is pretty standard UI, and I like the idea of having CRUD actions, but I'm facing a wall.

Is there a way of doing this all within `update.js.erb`. Could I send different `*.js.erb` responses? My workaround works, but is it the only way?

Thanks in advance I truly appreciate the support, experience and expertise!

#### EDIT

Code Examples:

```
# app/controllers/requests_controller.rb
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!
  before_action :set_request

  def update
    # permitted_request_params permits editable request fields
    if @request.update(permitted_request_params)
      # handles success
    else
      # handles failure
    end
  end

  def update_status
    if @request.update(status: params[:status])
      # handles success
    else
      # handles failure
    end
  end

  private
    # more stuff
end

# app/views/requests/update.js.erb
// code to signal that the update was successful or not on /requests/1/edit

# app/views/request/update_status.js.erb
// code that changes the UI to show the request was approved and signal successfully update of status
```

Ideally, everything could be accomplished within the `update.js.erb` file and I could then remove the `update_status` action.

#### EDIT 2

I've seen an example where someone made an `approve` and `decline` action. Maybe this would be better as it's more explicit if you were making a library to interface your application (e.g. Stripe, Heroku, Cloudflare, etc).

```
request.approve -> PUT /request/1/approve
```

I didn't really like my approach, but dumb-ed down like this doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: can you show your code so it is more clear what what you mean by a "workaround"?

Comment: Added some code examples

Comment: What's the difference between `permitted_update_params` and `permitted_status_update_params `? Can you give an example of the format of the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, having different `action`s for updating the same `resource` say `request` is not `DRY`. No matter from which page the request is coming from, the same particular `request` object is gonna get updated.

So, better to `reuse` the `update` action. To identify from which page the request is coming, you can give `name` to submit buttons.

```
<%= submit_tag 'Update', name: 'update_status_only' %>
<%= submit_tag 'Update', name: 'update_request' %>
```

then in `request_controller`

```
def update
  # permitted_request_params permits editable request fields
  if @request.update(permitted_request_params)
    # handles success
  else
    # handles failure
  end

  if params[:update_status_only]
    render 'update_status'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to figure out how to write a single Javascript file that gets sent with a few different HTML pages.

There are a couple ways to do this.

The easiest option is to put the file in `app/assets/javascripts` and write a `//= require myfile` line in `application.js`. This will get it included with every HTML response.

You could alternative use a [javascript_include_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag) to include a script on a per-page basis.

Besides loading the same script on two different pages, there's the question of how to actually write this script. It'll probably have to be refactored to be more generic (so that it works in two use-cases as opposed to one).

Comment: I'm not trying to include both scripts on the same page. I'm trying to respond to an AJAX request with JavaScript.